# get distinct items after applying filter in google datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have been trying to get distinct items with filter in google datastore using the following query:

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('Todo')
query.groupBy(['completed']);

query.filter('title', 'abc');
query.run(function (err, items) {
  console.log(err, items)
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
  }

  callback(null, items.map(entityToTodo));
});
```

and i got this error:

```
{ [Error: Precondition Failed] code: 412, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } } undefined
```

Is there any way I can get desired result?

Comment: i vaguely remember that query should be ordered by fields its grouping. try adding "query.order('completed');" before running the query